# Keep the max value of a column for each id and a value saved on another column that belongs to max into a new column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
    ID     CustId    ShName
0  456     Adsg09     Name1
1  876     T43535     Name2 
2  890     ED4388     Name2
3  763     YGT777     Name3
4  669     9877RT     Name4
5  432     TREDD5     Name1
```

I grouped the DataFrame based on CustId and ShName and counted the unique IDs per CustId to find the transactions per shop for each customer:

```
FShop = shopsData.groupby(['CustId','ShName'],as_index=True)['ID'].nunique().to_frame('Transactions per shop')
```

Now my FShop DataFrame looks like this:

```
                       
                       Transactions per shop
CustId    ShName      
------------------  
Adsg09     Name1                 7
           Name5                 5
T43535     Name2                 6
ED4388     Name2                 1
YGT777     Name3                 5
9877RT     Name4                 6
           Name3                 5
TREDD5     Name1                 1
```

What I want to accomplish is to find the max Transaction per shop for each CustId and then keep the ShName with the max transactions again for each CustId in the ShName column or in a new column.

The DataFrame should look like this (if we keep the ShName with max transaction per CustId in ShName column):

```
                       
                       Transactions per shop     
CustId    ShName      
------------------  
Adsg09     Name1                 7                
           Name1                 5                
T43535     Name2                 6
ED4388     Name2                 1
YGT777     Name3                 5
9877RT     Name4                 6
           Name4                 5
TREDD5     Name1                 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The following method should work. You may not need to sort.

```
FShop = FShop.reset_index().set_index("CustId")
                           .sort_values("Transactions per shop", ascending=False)
FShop["ShName"] = FShop.groupby("CustId", as_index=False).nth(0)["ShName"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything worked fine! Help much appreciated! @Gus

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ShName` to be the [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html)-ed value based on [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `CustId`, as follows:

```
FS = FShop.reset_index()
FS['ShName'] = (FS['ShName'].loc[
                                 FS.groupby('CustId', sort=False)['Transactions_per_shop']
                                   .transform('idxmax')
                                ]
               ).reset_index(drop=True)
FShop = FS.set_index(['CustId', 'ShName'])




print(FShop)


               Transactions_per_shop
CustId ShName                       
Adsg09 Name1                       7
       Name1                       5
T43535 Name2                       6
ED4388 Name2                       1
YGT777 Name3                       5
9877RT Name4                       6
       Name4                       5
TREDD5 Name1                       1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @SeaBean